# Which data types can be used for couchbase key

Tags: java, couchbase

I have to use CouchBase is my application and new to it. Can Any data type / data Structure (Array, List, Map) be used as CouchBase key.

Also,If I want to use a class (Student) Object as Couch Base key, is it possible?

```
/* Dummy class */
public class Student{

String name;

List<String> subjects;

}
```

Comment: Best way to know is to test it :) Normally, mostly strings or complex keys(array) are used. Therefore, I would not recommend using object(if it's supported). Keys should fast and easy to compare. Comparaing objects is certainly not optimized

Answer (score 0):

If objects you wish to use as keys are immutable (meaning they won't change state, and thus representation as a key) then there's nothing standing in your way. You could for example generate `.hashCode()` for your objects and use those as keys.